Modifying the code to better visualize data
I'm solving a certain physics problem that proceeds iteratively. The idea is to calculate recursively a function f. The function is said to be a solution if it obeys some kind of  convergence. A very schematic MWE would be
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

class Experiment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
        self.f = lambda x: 0 # Initial function

    def update_f(self):
        # Does something to f
        self.f = lambda x: f(x)**2 + 1

    def main_calculation(self):
        # For some definition of convergence
        while not self.convergence():
             self.update_f()

experiment = Experiment()
experiment.main_calculation()

Every time I want to peep at how a variable is changing through the calculation (for example by plotting) I have to go to the main code and change each method from inside, I find that quite clumsy and more importantly, annoying.
For example, say I want to look at what f looks like before and after it being updated. Then I should change for example main_calculation to
    def main_calculation(self):
        # For some definition of convergence
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        while not self.convergence():
             plt.plot(self.x, self.f(self.x), label='before')
             self.update_f()
             plt.plot(self.x, self.f(self.x), label='after')

This means creating more axes, which I already have many and also it clutters the code.
Is there a nicer way of doing this?

If the intermediate results are interesting to you, how about writing the intermediate values into a list or in a file? That option could be behind a boolean flag.

Which code lines do you regard as "clutter"? Ideally, you would like to eliminate all, but it's of course not possible. Which ones are the worst? Also, axes? Where are these axes that you want to eliminate? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

@NikoFohr I do that. But in some runs of the code I want to look at certain things related to the f function and some other runs i want to look at others. I want to find a way to make it so that I don't have to restructure all my code every time I am interested in a different quantity

The code lines I regard as clutter are the ones that wrap the self.update_f() line , and the initialization of fig, ax, which are needed if I want an organized and labeled plotting. I don't want to elminate the axes. Sometimes I want them, sometimes I don't. What I want is a more flexible way of defining the axes.

Do you always want to do the plotting or would you want to do something else? Can you get away by just adding a breakpoint() and looking around variable values? Is this a developer-time thing or something you want to do in the final product?

I guess it's a mixture of both. This code has a lot of steps to calculate something that is fairly easy to understand. I'd like it to be a black box in the sense that if this is used in the future, the code itself doesn't need to be touched.

The keyword here were wrappers. I did not know how to use wrappers since I didn't want to write a @plot_interesting_thing on top of every def method(self). However I can change the methods using wrappers externally. For example, what I am interested in plotting right now is a scatter plot that looks like (f_0(1), f_1(1)), (f_1(1), f_2(2)), ... . What I managed to do is wrap the function as follows.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Experiment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
        self.f = lambda x: 0 # Initial function

    def update_f(self):
        # Does something to f
        self.f = lambda x: f(x)**2 + 1

    def main_calculation(self):
        # For some definition of convergence
        while not self.convergence():
             self.update_f()

experiment = Experiment()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def fixed_point_wrapper(fun):
    def inner():
        a1 = experiment.f(1)
        experiment.update_f()
        ax.plot(a1, experiment.f(1))

experiment.update_f = fixed_point_wrapper(experiment.update_f)

experiment.main_calculation()
plt.show()

This way I can get the specific plot I want for this calculation
